# Combined response from multiple HTTP request from a loop

Tags: angular, rxjs

I would like to make several HTTP request asynchronously, then combine all of the response together into an array.

Something like below:

```
getSamples(genes) {
        genes.forEach(gene => {
            //This is the HTTP get request from other service which returns an observable array
            this.vsal.getSamples(gene).subscribe(sampleRequest => {
                //I want to join all the responses into sampleIdsSource
                this.sampleIdsSource.next(sampleRequest.samples);
            },
            e => {
                this.error.next(e);
            })
        });  
    }
```

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just turn each `gene` into an Observable and then `forkJoin` them. `forkJoin` will wait until all source Observable complete and will emit a single array with their results.

```
getSamples(genes) {
  const observables = genes.map(gene => this.vsal.getSamples(gene));
  return forkJoin(observable);
}
```